# How to fix an error related to Zend parameters?

Tags: magento, xampp, magento-2.0, magento2.2

I have a fatal error:
`Class Zend\Stdlib\Parameters contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods` (ArrayAccess::offsetUnset) in
`E:\xampp\htdocs\mage221\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\Parameters.php on line 14`

How to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 7):

Just Restart `xampp/wammp` OR `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

I take some step and it solved.

1. reset your server like xampp, wamp.
   give command to magento.
2. php bin/Magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/Magento setup:static-content:deploy
4. php bin/Magento cache:clean
5. php bin/Magento cache:flush

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this command and solved.
composer install && composer update -vv && 
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;

Answer (score 0):

@Pratik Kamani what if site in production and so many users on site if you do apche2 retart? Wan't they logged out?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can search for similar questions, or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question, and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: Ask questions, get answers, no distractions

Comment: Actually I wanted to put comment on Pratik Kamani answer but I dont have enough reputation so this was the only alternative to express myself.